# Is the <router-outlet> activating my component which I did not write a tag for?

Tags: angular, router-outlet

I'm currently reading through the code on the Angular getting started docs:
https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/getting-started-v0/stackblitz.html

I see how in `app.component.html`, the `top-bar.component` is being rendered because of `<app-top-bar></app-top-bar>`.  However, I don't see where the `product-list.component` is being rendered.  The only option I see is by the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.

In the [Router Outlet Docs](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet#description), it says:

> A router outlet will emit an activate event any time a new component
>   is being instantiated, and a deactivate event when it is being
>   destroyed.

Does this mean that the router outlet is activating the `product-list.component` once it is instantiated, causing it to be rendered on the screen?  If so, why is the top bar being left outside of the router outlet?  Why not just let the router outlet activate the top bar?

Here is `app.component.html`:

```
<app-top-bar></app-top-bar>

<div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different ways that you can call "html" to your principal page (app.component.html).

The first one is to put the "html" in your index and you can't change that, you will see always that page.

In your component you have something like this code:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-header',
templateUrl: './header.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
```

You have tu use "selector" for call in your html:

```
<app-header></app-header>
```

---

`router-outlet` is to use a single tag so you can change HTML depending on the routes.

In app-module you need to import product-list.component, for example:

```
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
```

An then you must define the routes in a variable:

```
const routes: Routes= [
{path: '', redirectTo:'/clientes', pathMatch: 'full'},
{path: 'product', component: NameComponent}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you call the selector like, `<app-top-bar></app-top-bar>` then it will call that component, but in this case below code is instantiating the product component:

```
 RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: ProductListComponent },
    ])
```

so,   `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` is activating the product component